# Structuring for nested class (C#)

Tags: c#, oop, derived-class

I'm drawing a blank how I need to structure these classes to get what I want - here's a simplified version of what I've got:

```
public abstract class DocumentBase
{
    public abstract class IndexingBase
    {
        public string universalField;
    }
    public IndexingBase myIndex;
}

public class ATypeOfDocument : DocumentBase
{
    public class Indexing : DocumentBase.IndexingBase
    {
        public string nonUniversalField;
    }

    public ATypeOfDocument()
    {
        this.myIndex = new Indexing();
    }
}
```

Which works, except I'm not able to access the nonUniversalField - because I'm accessing it through MyInstanceOfATypeOfDocument.myIndex, which is declared as IndexingBase.  I tried adding 'public new Indexing myIndex' in ATypeOfDocument, but that caused all sorts of problems (the big one being that there was then two indexing structures in an instance of ATypeOfDocument.)

I guess what I'm looking for is for this code to work:

```
ATypeOfDocument specDoc = new ATypeOfDocument();
DocumentBase baseDoc = new ATypeOfDocument();
specDoc.myIndex.nonUniversalField = "asdf";
specDoc.myIndex.universalField = "asdf";
baseDoc.myIndex.universalField = "asdf";
// ((ATypeOfDocument)baseDoc).myIndex.universalField should be "asdf"
```

Also, I apologize if I'm missing anything or not posting correctly; it's my first question on Stack Exchange.

Comment: You may have simplified your code too much - this will just work. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: @CodeCaster no, it won't.  Try to compile it.  It won't satisfy his desired use.

Comment: @David [I did](http://ideone.com/C7CvWg). Oh, the commented field should be **non**universal.

Comment: @CodeCaster You've specifically casted, which is a bit misleading (albeit appropriate based on your name). You should have added that to your comment.

Comment: @David in that IdeOne link I did not alter the code, I only omitted and uncommented. The op is talking about **non**UniversalField, but the commented line shows the `universalField`. It also doesn't help for readability that all fields carry the same value.

Comment: @CodeCaster if we're talking about readability, then nested classes wouldn't be your first choice either :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing another cast to access the `nonUniversalField`, namely of the `myIndex` to `ATypeOfDocument.Indexing`:

```
((ATypeOfDocument.Indexing)((ATypeOfDocument)baseDoc).myIndex).nonUniversalField
```

Comment: To your now-removed comment: no, an abstract class acts like an interface. Sure, you can extend it, but then the consumer has to know the extended type and cast to it. An alternative could be generics: `IndexableDocument<TIndex>`, where you expose a property of type `TIndex`.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid the cast?  Ultimately, I'm looking to allow an end-developer to write code like this:

    ATypeOfDocument newDoc = new ATypeOfDocument();
    newDoc.myIndex.fieldA = "asdf";
    newDoc.myIndex.fieldB = "asdf";
    newDoc.myIndex.fieldC = "asdf";
    newDoc.myIndex.fieldD = "asdf";
    newDoc.Save();

... or such.

Comment: @Kevin see the comment above.

Comment: You're probably right; I wish there was a cleaner way to access it, though.  "((ATypeOfDocument.Indexing)myDoc.myIndex).nonUniversalField" is a lot bulkier than "myDoc.myIndex.nonUniversalField"

Comment: You can do the latter with generics.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove `IndexingBase` and `Indexing` from the classes they're contained within and just make them separate classes. Declaring them as nested classes is creating the problem you're trying to solve, but what benefit are you getting in return?

The purpose of nested classes is to hide that inner class, which is an implementation detail of the outer class, from everything outside, in the same way that private variables and methods are hidden. In practice I don't think most programmers use them often. (Maybe some developers love them.) But the very second it adds complexity and forces you to solve a problem like this then it has no benefit at all.

Comment: I'll give that some thought, but I don't see how un-nesting the classes will fix my problem.  I'd still have a member 'myIndex' declared as an IndexingBase within the DocumentBase class, and the same issue getting to the nonUniversalField cleanly.